# Offering salah in front of a curtain that has parrot images

Tags: salat

Assalam alaikum,

Today I got one doubt while offering Isha namaz.

I am staying in a hotel. Towards qibla direction I have a glass window. On the other side of glass window, two statues are there. One more thing is the window can be covered by curtain which has images of a parrot.

While offering Isha, my own image appears in mirror. For the the above reasons I offer salah  by covering glass window with the curtain though I have images of parrot. This is the only option I see. I cannot change the hotel also.

Please tell me if this is correct way or not.

If it is not the correct way, please best possible approach to offer namaz.

Jazakallahu khair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you focus on the actual prayer and ignore any parrots, crows, or other birds.

God knows best, but I seriously doubt He cares about such minor issues.